# sklearn pipeline fit: AttributeError: lower not found

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I would like to use a pipeline in sklearn, like this:

```
corpus = load_files('corpus/train')

stop_words = [x for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')]  # Uppercase!

countvec = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 2))

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(corpus.data, corpus.target, test_size=0.9,
                                                    random_state=0)
x_train_counts = countvec.fit_transform(X_train)
x_test_counts = countvec.transform(X_test)

k_fold = KFold(n=len(corpus.data), n_folds=6)
confusion = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer',  CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier',  MultinomialNB()) ])

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:

    pipeline.fit(x_train_counts, y_train)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(x_test_counts)
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
AttributeError: lower not found
```

I have looked at this post:

[AttributeError: lower not found; using a Pipeline with a CountVectorizer in scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33605946/attributeerror-lower-not-found-using-a-pipeline-with-a-countvectorizer-in-scik)

but I am passing a list of bytes to the vectorizer, so that shouldnt be the problem.

**EDIT**

```
corpus = load_files('corpus')

stop_words = [x for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n')]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(corpus.data, corpus.target, test_size=0.5,
                                                    random_state=0)

k_fold = KFold(n=len(corpus.data), n_folds=6)
confusion = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    pipeline.fit(X_train[train_indices], y_train[train_indices])
    predictions = pipeline.predict(X_test[test_indices])
```

Now I get the error:

```
TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

**2ND EDIT**

```
corpus = load_files('corpus')

stop_words = [y for x in open('stopwords.txt', 'r').read().split('\n') for y in (x, x.title())]

k_fold = KFold(n=len(corpus.data), n_folds=6)
confusion = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer', CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier', MultinomialNB())])

for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    pipeline.fit(corpus.data, corpus.target)
```

Comment: wait, why did you do a train, test split and then kfold? folds are usually used when you don't have enough to test. Also you are folding on the corpus.data, which is problably different from your X_train which would be 50% shorter.

Comment: @Ale: Okay, i think I misunderstood kfold. I thought it was a way to shuffle test and training data around. The 2nd edit doesnt throw an error, but how do I now use the predict() function?

Comment: that's where you use the indices, in the kfold, to extract train and test data, see my edited answer. Or don't use kfold and train on X_train and test on X_test

Comment: @Ale Thanks a lot!! I think I got it now :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not using correctly the pipeline. You don't need to pass the data vectorized, the idea is that the pipeline vectorizes the data.

```
# This is done by the pipeline
# x_train_counts = countvec.fit_transform(X_train)
# x_test_counts = countvec.transform(X_test)

k_fold = KFold(n=len(corpus.data), n_folds=6)
confusion = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vectorizer',  CountVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier',  MultinomialNB()) ])

# also you are not using the indices...
for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:

    pipeline.fit(corpus.data[train_indices], corpus.target[train_indices])
    predictions = pipeline.predict(corpus.data[test_indices])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I changed my code, but I am getting a new error now! Could you have another look?

Comment: @user3813234 the folds should be done to corpus.data and corpus.target